# div information overlapping. should be bottom of its container

Tags: html, css, overlap

I have created a class called "category-product-info" which contains each of my sites product information (title, price, add to basket button). each product is in its own container which can clearly be seen. (id="product").

now I have put the following code into the category-product-info class to get everything to be positioned at the bottom of each container:

position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

but if you have a look at the page right now it overlaps All of the product info on top of each other, i'll try keep the page as is while I work on it so you can see. included the code below too..

http://bit.ly/1hfvCvH

HTML

```
<div class="span3">
    <div id="product"> 
        <div class="product-select <?=$counter;?>">
            <!-- ENABLE FOR TRIANGLES ON PRODUCT IMAGES -->
            <!-- <div class='triangle-container'><div class='triangle'><p>NEW!</p></div></div> -->
            <?php if ($row_rsCatalogue['fileId']){ ?>
                <div class="product-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'Product/'.($catRoot?$catRoot:'').$row_rsCatalogue['pageName']; ?>">
                    <img style="<?=$img_ratio;?>" src="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'upload/340w/'.$row_rsCatalogue['fileId'].'_'.$row_rsCatalogue['fileName']; ?>" alt="<?php echo (($row_rsCatalogue['metaKey'].' - '.$row_rsCatalogue['pageTitle'])); ?>" />
                </a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <div class="category-product-info">
                <div class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'Product/'.$catRoot.''.$row_rsCatalogue['pageName']; ?>"><?php echo ($row_rsCatalogue['pageTitle']); ?></a></div>
                <div class="price"><p><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /> </i> &pound;<?php echo  number_format(($catalogue->output_row_price($user)),2); ?></p></div>
                <!--div class="price"><p><i>from<br />only</i> &pound;<?php echo  number_format(($catalogue->output_row_price($user))*($site->row['vatRate']/100+1),2); ?></p></div-->
                <a href="<?php echo HTTP_HOST.'Product/'.($catRoot?$catRoot:'').$row_rsCatalogue['pageName']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?=HTTP_HOST;?>img/addtocart.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#products {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}

#product-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#product {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 350px;
}

#product:hover {
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#f8f8f8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f8f8f8 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f8f8f8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.price {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.category-product-info {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you change position absolute to relative in  **category-product-info** class

```
  .category-product-info {
bottom: 0;
position: relative;
 }
```

and give some similar height to **product-image** class to align perfect height to all div example like

```
 .product-image {
  height: 210px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `position:absolute` to any element, it is positioned relative to the nearest parent element which has the property `position:relative`.

And if no such element exists, then it defaults to `body`.

So, just give `position:relative` to `.span3` or `#product`.

Although, you should replace

```
<div id="product">
```

with

```
<div class="product">
```

And just use :

```
.product {
    position: relative;
}
```

as `ids` are unique throughout the page, and no 2 elements should have the same `id`, whereas same `class` can be applied to more than 1 element.

Comment: Although this worked, .span3 is apart of Twitter bootstrap which im using on this site. And may be used elsewhere multiple times, may break something else in future.

Comment: Then assign it to #product. Although, you should replace id="product" with class="product" as id's are unique throughout the page.

Answer (score 0):

position relative #product, span.3 is a container

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Are you reading my comment?, it states add position relative to the ID product. Thats an answer